# The fertility of the soil

Tags: homework, soil

I came across this question in my book, it says:

> The fertility of the soil increases when there is a lot of ....... in it.

The choices to fill the space were:

> Nitrogen - nodular bacteria - fungi

I would exclude fungi as in my course I don't have anything says that fungi affect the fertility of the soil. Both nitrogen and nodular bacteria are good choices and I am confused between them. Nitrogen is an important nutrient, nodular bacteria are the nitrogent-fixing bacteria, so both are important to the firtility of the soil, but I chose nitrogen, as I thought it is more correct, but I found that the answer was "nodular bacteria" so why is this? Is there anything I don't understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this paper from 1958 (page 2),

> ... **gaseous nitrogen** of the atmosphere represents a vast store of potential
>   fertility. It **is not directly available to plants**. Nitrogen-fixing bacteria, how-
>   ever, absorb this gas from the soil solution and convert it to cell protein.
>   When the cells die, other microbes attack the protein and convert the nitro-
>   genous constituents to ammonium, which then becomes an available nutrient.
>   Similarly, microbial action on plant and animal residues releases the many
>   combined nutrients from their unavailable forms.

From this, one of the criteria for soil to be fertile is the availability of nitrogen to be available to plants in a readily usable form. In a two stage process, one group of microbes (bacteria) fixes the nitrogen by converting into a protein, within their cells. When this group of microbes die, another group of microbes uses these proteins to produce ammonia, which is a nutrient that plants can use.

Also, as [this article states](http://www.astrobio.net/also-in-news/bacteria-needed-to-make-fertile-soil/), dead bacteria are critical to soil fertility, because nearly 40 percent of a the biomass of bacteria are converted to organic soil components.
strong text

**[The Nitrogen Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_cycle)**

[image]

Comment: Then you say that the correct answer to my MCQ is nitrogen?! You agree with me then. But what about the book answer?

Comment: @Asmaa: No. Plants cannot absorb nitrogen directly from the atmosphere, they need bacteria to make nitrogen in a form they can use.

Comment: Oh, OK, I got it.

Comment: @Fred The link on the nitrogen cycle seems to be broken. Is [this](http://wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2014/02/21/how-do-plants-get-their-nitrogen-from-the-air/) what you were referring to?

Answer (score 5):

#### What does 'nitrogen' mean?

Nitrogen might mean gaseous $N_2$. It might also mean compounds, which contain nitrogen, such as nitrate, ammonia and ammonium.

#### $N_2$

$N_2$ cannot be metabolized by most plants because it is to inert. You need bacteria or plants (e.g. Legume family plants) to perform nitrogen fixation. During this processes the $N_2$ is converted into bio-available compounds such as ammonia. If these plants/bacteria are not present, the $N_2$ is useless and does not increase the fertility.

#### Nitrate and Ammonium/Ammonium

Ammonium and nitrate can directly be 'used' by plants and soil bacteria. Therefore, if we provide these compounds, we increase the fertility.

#### Summary

Generally, 'nitrogen' does not increase the fertility of soils but depends on how it is bound - elemental or in a bio-available form. Therefore, 'nitrogen' does not necessarily increase the fertility. In contrast, nitrogen fixing bacteria do increase the fertility of the soil (also long as $N_2$ concentrations in the atmosphere are as high as present).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Nitrogen. Pay attention that nitrogen must be mineralized before it is available for plants:
https://cropaia.com/blog/nitrogen-in-plants/

Comment: Welcome to the site, but please do not repeat answers